# Find entries that have a specific file related to by Assets

Tags: assets

I would like to be able to link to all entries that have a specific file included using P&T Assets.
I have a page that displays the large version of an image which is called via this code:

```
{exp:assets:files file_id="{segment_2}"}
<img src="{url}" />
{/exp:assets:files}
```

So I know the file_id (and any other info stored by Assets), is there a way I can search through the entries looking for that Assets file_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure how to build the custom query, but I worked out this solution, but it's probably not the most efficient, but it works. I'm searching for the filename in the channel entries custom field instead of the file_id.
The original code now has an embed call to another template.

```
{exp:assets:files file_id="{segment_2}"}
<img src="{url}" />
{embed="includes/_related_entries" file="{filename}"}
{/exp:assets:files}
```

Then this is the embedded template (cf_images is the Assets custom field):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="yxz" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" search:cf_images="={embed:file}"}
<p><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}" title=""></a>{title}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a custom query against the exp_assets_selections table. Currently there's no other way.

Comment: I've not used a custom query before so wasn't sure of the syntax, so thought of another solution.